# how does steady-state error decrease as the pole of the compensator moves closer to the origin?

Tags: linear-systems, control-systems, pid

The steady-state error improves when the pole moves closer to the origin, as seen in lag or integral compensators with step input. Is there an intuitive explanation for this phenomenon?